# why can't Maven find the nd4j .jar file after adding the dependency to pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, nd4j

I created a maven program in intellij-idea with openjdk-20, and I put the dependency for nd4j in the dependencies section in pom.xml, and imported nd4j.*, but when I ran the program, it raised this error:

```
Could not find artifact org.nd4j:nd4j:jar:1.0.0-M2.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

I tried "running the Maven import with -U", which was what the compiler said would fix the error, but it still raised the same error. I also went to the repo.maven.apache.org website, and it didn't have nd4j there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to include nd4j dependencies the wrong way.  If I am reading [the instructions](https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/multi-project/explanation/maven) correctly, you are supposed to add the Deeplearning4j dependency:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-M2.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and a dependency for one of the nd4j backend modules; e.g.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-M2.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You have apparently used something like this instead:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>nd4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-M2.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

That doesn't work because that dependency denotes a parent POM not a JAR file.

---

> I also went to the repo.maven.apache.org website, and it didn't have nd4j there.

[It was there when I looked](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.nd4j/nd4j/1.0.0-M2.1).  But as I said, it is a POM file not a JAR file.

Comment: Hi, maintainer here. This is correct. You need to pick a backend. nd4j is just a parent artifact and doesn't do anything useful.